# Is he or she a she or a he?

Tags: nouns

Based on that **"a she"** and **"a he"** are nouns that can be used in combination to form compound nouns can we use them to speak about transgender (transsexual)?

- She is a he-she.
- That boy is a she-boy.

Comment: In some cultures those might be acceptable terms. Here in North America, they are considered to be rude/sexist and discriminatory. If someone *needs* to talk about sex or sexual preference, then I'd highly recommend using the politically correct terms. Transgender is one of them. I have a friend who calls himself 'queer'. He would not look kindly on someone he doesn't know referring to him that way. This is a slippery-slope -- err on the side of political correctness in any new social situation.

Comment: Those terms would be considered jocular at best and probably insulting.  I would not recommend using them unless you were extremely certain no one within earshot would be offended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of googling, I found out that the terms for a male with all the attributes of a woman are [ladyboy](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Ladyboy) and [shemale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shemale). I think that both the terms are used mainly in the porn industry — outside of that, the proper, not offensive terms may be ["transman"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trans_man) and ["transwoman"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trans_woman).

Comment: Yeh, I've checked. You're right!